# Producing a batch of events to the same kafka topic overwrite each other

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to produce two events to the same kafka topic in a batch, only the second event ends on kafka and the first is not sent.

```
// sudo code of what i'm doing

// producer
await kafka.produce(
  event1 { message: "vito", topic: "corleone" },
  event2 { message: "sonny", topic: "corleone" }
  event3 { message: "fredo", topic: "corleone" }
)

// consumer listening to topic "corleone"
kafka.handler(payload) {
  log(payload) // prints "fredo" but doesn't print "vito" or "sonnie"
}
```

What works though is if I have these events go to different topics:

```
// producer
await kafka.produce(
  event1 { message: "vito", topic: "corleone" },
  event2 { message: "sonny", topic: "deadinpart1" }
  event3 { message: "fredo", topic: "deadinpart2" }
)
```

If I do that, I receive all three events (by listening to the three topics) which makes me think that Kafka might not be supporting multiple messages to the same topic in a batch.

My producer settings looks like this:

```
const kafkaConfig: KafkaConfigSchema = {
  brokers: config().kafka.brokers, // array of brokers
  useSasl: config().kafka.useSasl, // true
  useSsl: config().kafka.useSsl, // true
  username: config().kafka.username,
  password: config().kafka.password,
  groupId: config().kafka.groupId, // a unique string
};
```

Are there any settings I am missing or am I doing something wrong architecturally by sending messages that share the topic in the same batch?

Comment: H How do you know all records were actually sent? Are you flushing the producer batches or waiting for an acknowledgement? Nothing is "overwriten"

Comment: i wait for acknowledgement from the producer and receive them on the other end in the consumer

Comment: you can use kafka tool for checking them http://www.kafkatool.com/